# Showing variable from another file in a LCD screen raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a bme280 temperature and humudity sensor and I want to show the temperature and the humidity in the LCD screen I have. I also want it to automaticly update in a determinate time. The problem is that I'm trying to show the variable and I get an error.

This is my bme2890_senosr.py code:

```py
import bme280
import smbus2
import time
from time import sleep
import math


port = 1
address = 0x76 # Adafruit BME280 address. Other BME280s may be different
bus = smbus2.SMBus(port)


def round_up(n, decimals=0):
    multiplier = 100 ** decimals
    return math.ceil(n * multiplier) / multiplier




bme280.load_calibration_params(bus,address)

def update_sensor_data():
    bme280_data = bme280.sample(bus,address)
    global temperatura
    temperatura = round(bme280_data.temperature)
    data = {
        'humitat': round(bme280_data.humidity),
        'pressio': round(bme280_data.pressure),
        'temperatura': round(bme280_data.temperature)

    }
    return data
```

This is my screen.py code

```py
from time import *
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/jordi/weather-station/data')
from bme280_sensor import update_sensor_data

mylcd = I2C_LCD_driver.lcd()


while(True):
    update_sensor_data()
    mylcd.lcd_display_string("Temp: %d%sC" % (temperatura, chr(223)), 1)
    sleep(1)
```

I have tried to put the variable as show in the code but got the error "NameError: name 'temperatura' is not defined.

Comment: `update_sensor_data()` is returning the desired data, in the form of a dictionary - but you're just throwing that data away when you call the function.

Comment: `data = update_sensor_data()` and `data['temperatura']` ...